# is it possible for an admin to access or report on the login records for users in salesforce?

Tags: reporting, administration

is it possible for an admin user to create a report on the login records for users in salesforce? I want to be able to analyze the login records for particular users, to a analyze login frequencies etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely.  You would need to run a report on the user object.  You can report on their login history and see there last log in, even see what IP address they logged in from.  This should help get you started.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard report in the administrative reports folder named 
"Users Logged in This Week" which report lists all of the users who have logged in to Salesforce in the past seven days. This can be a good start to create your own report matching your requirements

You can find more details here https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_administrative.htm&language=en_US